# GLMER Output from R, meaning of .sig01, .sig02, .sig03

Tags: r, output, glm, lme4

when computing profile confidence intervals using `confint(m1)` where `m1` is a `glmer()` model there is a term ( or a few ) at the top which are labelled `.sig01, .sig02`, I can't find any documentation which explains what these mean though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably didn't find the documentation for the `'merMod'` class method of `confint`. In `?lme4::confint.merMod` the following can be read at the parameters:

> `oldNames`: (logical) use old-style names for variance-covariance parameters, 
>              e.g. `".sig01"`, rather than newer (more informative) names such as
>              `"sd_(Intercept)|Subject"`? (See signames argument to profile).

The default option for `oldNames` is `TRUE`. Setting it to `FALSE` will give you a clearer output.

***Example***

```
library(lme4)
(gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
              data = cbpp, family = binomial))
confint(gm1, oldNames=FALSE)
#                          2.5 %     97.5 %
# sd_(Intercept)|herd  0.3460732  1.0999743
# (Intercept)         -1.9012119 -0.9477540
# period2             -1.6167830 -0.4077632
# period3             -1.8010241 -0.5115362
# period4             -2.5007502 -0.8007554
```